# Can I say a "voice 'rang' with irritation"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Can I say that a "voice *rang* with irritation", as in the following example?

> “Get into the stance!” for the first time that day, the old man's voice rang with irritation, so familiar to Jack.

Comment: Unless you wish to use 'ring' as a quotative verb ('As "Keep off the grass!" rang out across the quad ...') (and I'd say it needs to be 'ring out' and follow the quote directly), the whole string starting with 'for' is a complete sentence and needs a capital _F_. If it's obvious who's speaking (and it _is_ here), a quote doesn't need a speech tag.

Comment: You can say what you like, but it appears that you are asking an opinion on the use of a metaphor. Questions of that sort are (in my interpretation of the remit of this site) off topic. I believe there is another SE site for creative writing. (And, of course, my opinion is of no consequence, but I wouldn’t write that myself.)

Answer (score 2):

His "voice rang with irritation" is fine. One definition of the verb "ring" is "to have a sound or character expressive of some quality". ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ring))

Examples are:

- in [DH Lawrence](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Delphi_Complete_Works_of_D_H_Lawrence_Il/ElEbAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) "His voice rang with a painful elation."
- from [Pall Mall Magazine](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Pall_Mall_Magazine/JsohAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) in 1894 "His voice rang with a depth of feeling..."
- From Collier's Magazine in 1956 "The strong voice rang with rage." (via Google Books, can't seem to link).

If you search Google Books for "voice rang with" you will see a lot of other examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such great advice! I never thought about Google Books!

Comment: What about OP's example, which includes a quote?

Comment: Ring, irritation, fine? That’s just your opinion and you don’t quote that precise usage. In my opinion it is incongruous (“tinkle with irritation” if you “ring with rage”) but I don’t give answers that are just opinions. Should you?